# Using SQL Server, how can I join records to the minimum value of all 'similar' records in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, minimum

[please forgive formatting errors-- first post here and I tried earnestly to do it right]

Functionally speaking, I'm simply trying to find the items that have the lowest price in its grouping of 'like' items.  For example-- there are tons of wines, but I need to find the lowest priced 750ml RED as well as WHITE; there are tons of cheeses, but I need to find the lowest priced 8oz CHEDDAR as well as FETA; etc.

All solutions I've found say to do the same thing I have in my code.  **There must be a problem with my "self join".  The select query on its own runs in less than 10 seconds, and so does the nested select.  When I try to join them, though, my query hangs and never finishes.**  There must be some way to do this join successfully.

I have millions of rows of data I'm pulling from.  Each row is a unique item/store combination.  My nested select is trying to find the lowest price we have for items that are NOT "name" brand; the lowest price is found among 'like' items, as determined by the columns: store_name, category, subcategory, class, package_desc2, unit_name, chk (in my query, "chk" is determined by the result of two different columns).

This gives me the distinct list of all combinations of the aforementioned columns with the lowest price for each.  I'm trying to join THAT to the non "name" brand items to see what the exact item(s) are that have that low price we found in the nested select.  Any help is appreciated!  I've been at this for days and can't figure it out.

SQL here:

```
SELECT b.zone_name, 
       b.store_name, 
       b.family, 
       b.category, 
       b.subcategory, 
       b.class, 
       b.team, 
       b.subteam, 
       b.pos_dept, 
       b.brand_name, 
       b.item_description, 
       b.upc, 
       b.package_desc1         pkg, 
       b.package_desc2         sz, 
       b.unit_name, 
       CASE 
         WHEN b.good = 'good' 
               OR b.how_good = 1 THEN 'YES' 
         ELSE 'NO' 
       END                     AS chk, 
       b.eff_pricetype, 
       b.eff_price             low_price, 
       b.cd                    dollar_sales, 
       b.cu                    unit_sales, 
       b.cgm                   margin_dollars, 
       b.cgm / Nullif(b.cd, 0) AS margin_pct, 
       b.deleted_item, 
       b.discontinue_item, 
       b.not_available, 
       b.remove_item, 
       b.recall_flag, 
       CASE 
         WHEN 
SUM( 
Isnull(b.deleted_item, 0) + Isnull(b.discontinue_item, 0) + Isnull(b.not_available, 0) + Isnull(b.remove_item, 0) + Isnull(b.recall_flag, 0)) = 0 THEN
         'NO' 
  ELSE 'YES' 
END                     AS istatus, 
d.low 
FROM   mytable b 
       INNER JOIN(SELECT c.store_name, 
                         c.category, 
                         c.subcategory, 
                         c.class, 
                         c.package_desc2, 
                         c.unit_name, 
                         CASE 
                           WHEN c.good = 'good' 
                                 OR c.how_good = 1 THEN 'YES' 
                           ELSE 'NO' 
                         END              AS chk, 
                         MIN(c.eff_price) low 
                  FROM   mytable c 
                  WHERE  store_name = 'some store' 
                         AND brand_name NOT LIKE '%name%' 
                         AND weeks = 'Last 12 weeks' 
                         AND ( eff_pricetype = 'REG' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'EDV' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'GBC' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'CMP' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'LIN' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'FRZ' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'GBB' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'EDLP' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'GBN' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'GBR' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'MKT' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'COMP' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'R' 
                                OR eff_pricetype = 'COM' ) 
                         AND ( family = 'carrots' 
                                OR family = 'tomatoes' 
                                OR family = 'Cheese' 
                                OR family = 'Coffee' 
                                OR family = 'peppers' 
                                OR family = 'milk' 
                                OR family = 'oil' 
                                OR family = 'season' 
                                OR family = 'Housewares' 
                                OR family = 'paper' 
                                OR family = 'Meat' 
                                OR family = 'soup' 
                                OR family = 'nuts' 
                                OR family = 'pizza' 
                                OR family = 'potatoes' 
                                OR family = 'Seafood' 
                                OR family = 'beer' 
                                OR family = 'vitamins' 
                                OR family = 'Tea' 
                                OR family = 'Wine' 
                                OR family = 'beans' ) 
                  GROUP  BY c.store_name, 
                            c.category, 
                            c.subcategory, 
                            c.class, 
                            c.package_desc2, 
                            c.unit_name, 
                            c.good, 
                            c.how_good 
                  HAVING MIN(c.eff_price) > 0) AS d 
         ON b.store_name = d.store_name 
            AND b.category = d.category 
            AND b.subcategory = d.subcategory 
            AND b.class = d.class 
            AND b.package_desc2 = d.package_desc2 
            AND b.unit_name = d.unit_name 
            AND CASE 
                  WHEN b.good = 'good' 
                        OR b.how_good = 1 THEN 'YES' 
                  ELSE 'NO' 
                END = d.chk 
            AND b.eff_price = d.low 
WHERE  store_name = 'some store' 
       AND brand_name NOT LIKE '%name%' 
       AND weeks = 'Last 12 weeks' 
       AND ( eff_pricetype = 'REG' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'EDV' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'GBC' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'CMP' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'LIN' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'FRZ' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'GBB' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'EDLP' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'GBN' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'GBR' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'MKT' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'COMP' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'R' 
              OR eff_pricetype = 'COM' ) 
       AND ( family = 'carrots' 
              OR family = 'tomatoes' 
              OR family = 'Cheese' 
              OR family = 'Coffee' 
              OR family = 'peppers' 
              OR family = 'milk' 
              OR family = 'oil' 
              OR family = 'season' 
              OR family = 'Housewares' 
              OR family = 'paper' 
              OR family = 'Meat' 
              OR family = 'soup' 
              OR family = 'nuts' 
              OR family = 'pizza' 
              OR family = 'potatoes' 
              OR family = 'Seafood' 
              OR family = 'beer' 
              OR family = 'vitamins' 
              OR family = 'Tea' 
              OR family = 'Wine' 
              OR family = 'beans' ) 
GROUP  BY b.zone_name, 
          b.store_name, 
          b.family, 
          b.category, 
          b.subcategory, 
          b.class, 
          b.team, 
          b.subteam, 
          b.pos_dept, 
          b.brand_name, 
          b.item_description, 
          b.upc, 
          b.package_desc1, 
          b.package_desc2, 
          b.unit_name, 
          d.org, 
          b.eff_pricetype, 
          b.eff_price, 
          b.cd, 
          b.cu, 
          b.cgm, 
          b.deleted_item, 
          b.discontinue_item, 
          b.not_available, 
          b.remove_item, 
          b.recall_flag, 
          d.low, 
          b.good, 
          b.how_good
```

Comment: Can you give the table structure and indexes? Also, the data structure is problematic and it is likely it will never be performing. Stores should be their own table, and depending how they are organized category and subcategories and famiies and eff_pricetype.

Comment: Yeah, that's tough.  reg_data_cube is actually a view with no indexes.  The tables that constitute the view have their own indexes, but I only have access to the view, and I can't alter it.  :(

Comment: Check the EXPLAIN, but I don't think there is much you can do to improve without indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code and possibly improve performance by changing your family and pricetype clauses to use IN instead of OR.

For example:

```
   AND eff_pricetype IN ('REG','EDV','GBC','CMP','LIN','FRZ',
                         'GBB','EDLP','GBN','GBR','MKT','COMP','R','COM') 

   AND family IN ('carrots','tomatoes','Cheese','Coffee', etc...
```

Also, if your subqueries are working as you say they are, you could put them into two different table variables and then join them.

Comment: thanks for your response!  i'll give table variables a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: i actually used a temp table and added an ID column, which was just reflecting row number, as primary key.  it ran in 14 seconds.  thanks!